# Finding growth rate of T(n) of a code segment

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis

I am presented with the following code segment and asked to find the growth rate, which can be done by finding the number of times the variable sum is incremented:

```
sum = 0
for i = 1 to 2 * n
 for j = 1 to i * i
   for k = 1 to j
     sum++
```

I tried making this into a function called `run(n)` in Python that returns sum and got `run(1) = 11`, `run(2) = 192`, `run(3) = 1183`, and `run(4) = 4488`.  However, my book only presents 3 possible answers, those being $\Theta(n^4)$, $\Theta(n^5)$, and $\Theta(n^6)$.

I don't think my results match any of these choices. I might be confused as to what the question is asking as it says

> present answers in terms of summations

or my code might be incorrect, but I am confused on what to do next. I am very new to algorithms, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The innermost loop increments `sum` exactly $j$ times. The middle loop runs $i^2$ times with increasing values of $j$ so it increments `sum` $\dfrac{i^2(i^2+1)}2$ times. And finally, the outer loop runs $2n$ times, for a total of $$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{i^2(i^2+1)}2=\frac{n (1 + 2 n) (1 + 4 n) (2 + 3 n + 6 n^2)}{15}$$ incrementations. [Thanks to Wolfram Alpha.]

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the number of times the `for i` is executed, $J$ the number of times `for j`, and $K$ the number of times `for k` is executed.

1. $I$ is $\Theta(n)$ times
2. $J$ is $\Theta(I \cdot I) = \Theta(n^2)$ times
3. $K$ is $\Theta(J) = \Theta(n^2)$

The correct answer is the product of $I$, $J$ and $K$, i.e., $\Theta(n \cdot n^2 \cdot n^2) = \Theta(n^5)$.

Comment: That was a very clear explanation, thank you!

Comment: Caution, this method can lead to false results. Take an outer loop for $i$ from $1$ to $n$, and inner loop from $1$ to $2^i$. You would say $\Theta(n)\cdot\Theta(2^n)=\Theta(n\cdot2^n)$ though the correct answer is $\Theta(2^n)$.